# Cisco RV016 dual WAN and VPN setup

Tags: networking, vpn, router

I have a VPN of several RV016 routers and I want to set some of them with 2 ISPs. I plug the two ISP cables in WAN 1 and 2 ports and configure the router to "Intelligent Balancer(Auto Mode)". It works ok like that, but the VPNs that I set use the public IP of the provider. For example if I have 5 VPNs set for ISP1 (WAN1) and the balancer sends the request trough WAN2 it can't use any of the configured VPNs because the public IP is different. How do I deal with this problem?